# error in RSA key paramiko lib

Tags: python, paramiko

I m using mac and have added rsa key on desktop

The path I 'm using is

```
host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='~/Desktop/test_rsa.key')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vidit/PycharmProjects/untitled6/server.py", line 7, in <module>
    host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='~/Desktop/test_rsa.key')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 163, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file('RSA', filename, password)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 267, in _read_private_key_file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/test_rsa.key'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `~` in the path of a file directly. It is a shell feature and expanded by the shell.

Use `os.path.expanduser(path)` to expand the `~` in the file path before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `~` in Python paths. Try hardcoding your home directory and it will work.

You can use `expanduser()` if you want to use tilde (`~`)

```
from os.path import expanduser    
keypath = expanduser("~/Desktop/test_rsa.key")
```

Comment: `expanduser()` can be used directly if the path starts with `~`. There is no need to split the path into components and reassemble them later.